# How to scroll to the new element of a ScrollViewer automatically in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollviewer, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a chat app on Avaloni UI. Messages are displayed in the ScrollViewer. I need to scroll the list of messages to a new message when I receive or send a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd()` [method](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/56950402d91267c135f474c5a9156ab9da0cdc46/src/Avalonia.Controls/ScrollViewer.cs#L494).

Here is an usage example from an app of mine:

```
public class ClientPage : UserControl
{
    private ScrollViewer messageLogScrollViewer;

    public ClientPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        messageLogScrollViewer = this.FindControl<ScrollViewer>("MessageLogScrollViewer");
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public void ScrollTextToEnd()
    {
        messageLogScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Depending on your specific use case you might instead need to use the `ScrollViewer.LineDown()` [method](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/56950402d91267c135f474c5a9156ab9da0cdc46/src/Avalonia.Controls/ScrollViewer.cs#L430) or any other of the provided methods.

Additionally you can also set the [Offset](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/56950402d91267c135f474c5a9156ab9da0cdc46/src/Avalonia.Controls/ScrollViewer.cs#L253) yourself.

Comment: OOO! Thank you very much! You will save me! I've been doing this for about a week)